# MinIO doesn't log OIDC errors while using STS in version 2022

Tags: minio

I am using MinIO 2020, I have configured MinIO for OIDC (Keycloak), I am using MinIO Java SDK to talk to MinIO STS. When STS has an error, for example, the OIDC token is used before token issue time, then the MinIO would log an appropriate message. I am trying to migrate to MinIO 2022, I don't see the log of STS error messages. Has anyone faced this problem?

MinIO 2022 OIDC/STS is functional. I don't see the log of STS error messages.